# Error 503 on running selenium tests in jetty (LifecycleExecutionException)

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, selenium, maven-jetty-plugin

I am trying to run my selenium Integration tests in jetty, But I am getting a Error 503 Service-unavialable on the browser for all the test classes. Here is my pom plugin for running tests.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <contextPath>/</contextPath>
      <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>start</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <daemon>true</daemon>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>stop</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <background>true</background>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>start-selenium</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>start-server</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>stop-selenium</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>stop-server</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>selenium-tests</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <skip>false</skip>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>none</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Here are the error messages I am getting after mvn install

```
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/kumuda/workspace/Music/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.writeSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:641)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:615)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I was running out of same issues and fixed by updating dependency. Here is the solution.

Include the selenium dependency like,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.43.0</version>
  <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
</dependency>
```

Here the scope is very important because by default it is in "test" scope. We need to remove that one. Otherwise while running "mvn jetty:run" will not load that dependency.